# Why Ubuntu desktop 20.04 boot is very slow [~3min to login screen]

Tags: boot, 20.04

I have tried tweaking few things, like

- removing/disabling services,
- checked HDD iostat [~ 120 MB/s avg read rate].

everything seems fine. But still it is taking ~3min to boot.

Output of `systemd-analyze plot` can be found in the [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AHGv-vfSchO8Wv4zw2D0xaT-Vn7o_J5H/view?usp=sharing)

Output of `systemd-analyze blame`

```
2min 140ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
   31.766s systemd-journal-flush.service
   28.994s dev-sdb1.device
   27.573s snapd.seeded.service
   25.841s udisks2.service
   25.712s snapd.service
   24.896s networkd-dispatcher.service
   22.360s accounts-daemon.service
   16.608s dev-loop15.device
   16.508s dev-loop13.device
   15.523s dev-loop5.device
   15.307s dev-loop7.device
   15.283s dev-loop8.device
   15.229s dev-loop12.device
   14.963s dev-loop6.device
   14.900s polkit.service
   14.875s dev-loop14.device
   14.799s dev-loop0.device
   14.478s avahi-daemon.service
   14.418s NetworkManager.service
   14.074s switcheroo-control.service
   14.067s thermald.service
   14.063s wpa_supplicant.service
   14.062s systemd-logind.service
   13.809s dev-loop1.device
   13.633s dev-loop9.device
   12.690s dev-loop10.device
   12.456s dev-loop11.device
   12.424s dev-loop2.device
   11.756s dev-loop3.device
   11.460s dev-loop4.device
    9.932s ModemManager.service
    9.213s systemd-udevd.service
    8.774s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
    8.357s smartmontools.service
    7.584s ufw.service
    6.966s systemd-resolved.service
    6.229s gpu-manager.service
    6.220s grub-initrd-fallback.service
    5.772s grub-common.service
    5.518s apport.service
    5.455s apparmor.service
    5.176s lm-sensors.service
    5.144s rsyslog.service
    5.013s kexec.service
    4.749s rc.local.service
    3.761s hddtemp.service
    3.399s networking.service
    3.354s e2scrub_reap.service
    3.320s monopd.service
    3.020s sysstat.service
    2.286s snap-core-9289.mount
    2.233s snapd.apparmor.service
    1.877s systemd-sysusers.service
    1.834s binfmt-support.service
    1.650s snap-core-9436.mount
    1.608s snap-core18-1705.mount
    1.581s snap-core18-1754.mount
    1.571s gdm.service
    1.560s apt-daily.service
    1.536s snap-core20-634.mount
    1.510s inetd.service
    1.492s snap-electron\x2dmail-24.mount
    1.491s snap-electron\x2dmail-25.mount
    1.474s systemd-modules-load.service
    1.463s snap-gimp-273.mount
    1.462s snap-gimp-281.mount
    1.386s snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount
    1.284s ssh.service
    1.254s kerneloops.service
    1.208s user@119.service
    1.192s dev-disk-by\x2duuid-820bee40\x2d75ec\x2d4794\x2daf59\x2d497ba69ebbe8.swap
    1.180s systemd-timesyncd.service
    1.162s setvtrgb.service
    1.135s snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-13.mount
    1.021s systemd-sysctl.service
     990ms keyboard-setup.service
     981ms upower.service
     732ms systemd-random-seed.service
     668ms modprobe@drm.service
     666ms systemd-journald.service
     607ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
     601ms dev-hugepages.mount
     600ms dev-mqueue.mount
     600ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
     599ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
     523ms dns-clean.service
     510ms console-setup.service
     499ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
     476ms snap-gtk2\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-9.mount
     441ms kmod-static-nodes.service
     428ms atd.service
     427ms atieventsd.service
     404ms colord.service
     396ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1502.mount
     343ms pppd-dns.service
     297ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
     288ms user@1000.service
     271ms snap-snap\x2dstore-415.mount
     243ms snap-snap\x2dstore-467.mount
     189ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount
     173ms ifupdown-pre.service
     157ms plymouth-start.service
     144ms alsa-restore.service
     112ms systemd-remount-fs.service
      88ms openvpn.service
      78ms systemd-user-sessions.service
      55ms systemd-update-utmp.service
      53ms finalrd.service
      51ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
      49ms rtkit-daemon.service
      41ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
      24ms user-runtime-dir@119.service
      19ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
      11ms plymouth-read-write.service
      11ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
      11ms resolvconf-pull-resolved.service
      11ms kexec-load.service
       3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
       3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
     980us snapd.socket
```

Hadware information:

```
*-memory
   description: System memory
   physical id: 0
   size: 16GiB

*-cpu
   product: AMD FX(tm)-8350 Eight-Core Processor
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
   physical id: 1
   bus info: cpu@0
   size: 1399MHz
   capacity: 4GHz

*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: e5
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
```

Output of `cat /etc/default/grub`

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="crashkernel=2G-6G:256M,6G-8G:512M,8G-:768M"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash noresume"

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

**Note:**
Years ago it was a fresh install (Ubuntu LTS 12.04 or 14.04 I can't remember now). Then it was updated to latest LTS every 2 years using `sudo do-release-upgrade`

Initially it was running with different hardware setup

- Intel Core 2 duo processor
- Asus mother board.
- 4 GB RAM.

Then it changed into current setup

**Edit**: Updated as per @heynnema request.

`$ free -h`

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       763Mi        12Gi        34Mi       2.0Gi        14Gi
Swap:         3.4Gi          0B       3.4Gi
```

`$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab`

```
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=820bee40-75ec-4794-af59-497ba69ebbe8 none            swap    sw              0       0
#/dev/sdc2: UUID="820bee40-75ec-4794-af59-497ba69ebbe8" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="000de4b8-02"
```

`$ sudo blkid`

```
[sudo] password for sourav:
/dev/sdb1: UUID="6955c8fd-22d3-4b9b-8a29-f98cec0419bb" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000de4b8-01"
/dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop3: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop4: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop5: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop6: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop7: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sdd: UUID="f836547b-4a89-7446-abac-281f4559fb1e" UUID_SUB="390af95a-5039-db0b-4e20-d50b472d70cf" LABEL="ubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdb2: UUID="820bee40-75ec-4794-af59-497ba69ebbe8" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="000de4b8-02"
/dev/sdb3: LABEL="DATA_790" UUID="201855474559DE32" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="atari" PARTUUID="000de4b8-03"
/dev/sdb5: UUID="1cdafd4a-1908-4bff-be5c-6ecfe722f53b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="000de4b8-05"
/dev/sdb6: UUID="C7A7-EC12" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="000de4b8-06"
/dev/sda: UUID="f836547b-4a89-7446-abac-281f4559fb1e" UUID_SUB="272a4d7f-bd7f-3a05-b9be-143179b4731c" LABEL="ubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/sdc: UUID="f836547b-4a89-7446-abac-281f4559fb1e" UUID_SUB="42ab19e9-932b-6318-c23f-2c6f7fb9e48d" LABEL="ubuntu:0" TYPE="linux_raid_member"
/dev/md127p1: LABEL="DATA_100G" UUID="258b4ae7-f26d-4648-a332-105d71998b40" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="7b1fc87a-01"
/dev/md127p3: LABEL="DATA_1.8T" UUID="796B821272CAD4DC" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="atari" PARTUUID="7b1fc87a-03"
/dev/md127p5: UUID="e9918fc1-6f8e-4c37-9b60-0d7342d46f07" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="7b1fc87a-05"
/dev/loop8: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop9: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop10: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop11: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop12: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop13: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop14: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop15: TYPE="squashfs"
```

`$ cat /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

```
RESUME=UUID=820bee40-75ec-4794-af59-497ba69ebbe8
```

`$ sudo lshw -C memory`

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: V1.4
       date: 12/24/2015
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification uefi
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 5
       slot: L1-Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 6
       slot: L2-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 7
       slot: L3-Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
       capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 27
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
          product: TS1GLK64V6H
          vendor: Transcend
          physical id: 0
          serial: 000ABB8B
          slot: A1_DIMM0
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-04-16 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 2e26c9bbd21cdca248baaea29aeffb920afcc32a) Synchronous [empty]
          product: Array1_PartNumber1
          vendor: A1_Manufacturer1
          physical id: 1
          serial: A1_SerNum1
          slot: A1_DIMM1
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
          product: V01L3LF8GB52852816
          vendor: Undefined
          physical id: 2
          serial: 00000000
          slot: A1_DIMM2
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2020-04-16 17:42+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 2e26c9bbd21cdca248baaea29aeffb920afcc32a) Synchronous [empty]
          product: Array1_PartNumber3
          vendor: A1_Manufacturer3
          physical id: 3
          serial: A1_SerNum3
          slot: A1_DIMM3
```

Additional

`$ lsblk`

```
loop0         7:0    0    97M  1 loop  /snap/core/9289
loop1         7:1    0    55M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1705
loop2         7:2    0  96.5M  1 loop  /snap/core/9436
loop3         7:3    0    55M  1 loop  /snap/core18/1754
loop4         7:4    0    61M  1 loop  /snap/core20/634
loop5         7:5    0   164M  1 loop  /snap/electron-mail/24
loop6         7:6    0 164.6M  1 loop  /snap/electron-mail/25
loop7         7:7    0 176.4M  1 loop  /snap/gimp/281
loop8         7:8    0 255.6M  1 loop  /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop9         7:9    0 175.9M  1 loop  /snap/gimp/273
loop10        7:10   0  62.1M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
loop11        7:11   0   132K  1 loop  /snap/gtk2-common-themes/9
loop12        7:12   0  54.8M  1 loop  /snap/gtk-common-themes/1502
loop13        7:13   0  49.8M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/467
loop14        7:14   0  43.2M  1 loop  /snap/snap-store/415
loop15        7:15   0   140K  1 loop  /snap/gtk2-common-themes/13
sda           8:0    1 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md127       9:127  0   1.8T  0 raid5 
  ├─md127p1 259:0    0  93.1G  0 part  
  ├─md127p2 259:1    0     1K  0 part  
  ├─md127p3 259:2    0   1.7T  0 part  
  └─md127p5 259:3    0   4.7G  0 part  
sdb           8:16   1 931.5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1        8:17   1  95.4G  0 part  /
├─sdb2        8:18   1   3.4G  0 part  [SWAP]
├─sdb3        8:19   1 731.2G  0 part  
├─sdb4        8:20   1     1K  0 part  
├─sdb5        8:21   1 100.6G  0 part  
└─sdb6        8:22   1   992M  0 part  
sdc           8:32   1 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md127       9:127  0   1.8T  0 raid5 
  ├─md127p1 259:0    0  93.1G  0 part  
  ├─md127p2 259:1    0     1K  0 part  
  ├─md127p3 259:2    0   1.7T  0 part  
  └─md127p5 259:3    0   4.7G  0 part  
sdd           8:48   1 931.5G  0 disk  
└─md127       9:127  0   1.8T  0 raid5 
  ├─md127p1 259:0    0  93.1G  0 part  
  ├─md127p2 259:1    0     1K  0 part  
  ├─md127p3 259:2    0   1.7T  0 part  
  └─md127p5 259:3    0   4.7G  0 part
```

**Solution:** For this case plymouth was the culprit. Thanks to @heynnema!

Detailed `systemd-analyze plot` of [before (~188 sec)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AHGv-vfSchO8Wv4zw2D0xaT-Vn7o_J5H/view?usp=sharing) and [after (~45 sec)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBcoW49QoywWZpyDOQ3RMS9cSznCcHm4/view?usp=sharing) removing plymouth

Other changes made during troubleshooting

- Updated `/etc/default/grub` with

  - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
  - `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""`
- Removed psensor `$ sudo apt remove psensor`
- Stripped down to only core snap packages (`core, core18, core20, gnome-3-34-1804, gtk-common-themes, gtk2-common-themes, snap-store`)

Comment: If you do not have any other OS alongside Ubuntu, you can set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to 0 instead of 10. This way, you can reduce 10 seconds of bootup time. It looks like the snap packages are taking some time to load. Replace snaps with apt packages if you can.

Comment: It is dual boot, alongside fedora 32. I have removed packages installed through snap. For example spotify

Comment: What is "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="crashkernel=2G-6G:256M,6G-8G:512M,8G-:768M""?

Comment: Try `sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth` and select ubuntu-logo and see if that speeds things up. Report back.

Comment: Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the exact make/model # of your computer.

Comment: @heynnema,
`crashkernel` kernel parameter was already there, I modified it by [this guidence](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/59432).

Output of `sudo dmidecode`
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1syB6YotLAN3reN4q8LKodpK9qUFk6-Q2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @heynnema,

changed ubuntu-log.plymount using `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and there is performance improvement.

`1min 39.480s plymouth-quit-wait.service`. I will update about consistency later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GRUB**

Your `/etc/default/grub` is incorrect. Edit it...

`sudo -H /etc/default/grub`

Change this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="crashkernel=2G-6G:256M,6G-8G:512M,8G-:768M"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash noresume"
```

To this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

`sudo update-grub`

`reboot`

**fsck**

`fsck` all of your disks. Your RAIDs may have a different device name than sdXX. Adjust as necessary.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB in “Try Ubuntu” mode
- open a `terminal` window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/sdXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdXX`, replacing `sdXX` with the number you found earlier
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**plymouth**

Remove `plymouth` from the system, with:

```
sudo apt-get purge plymouth
```

This will reduce the boot time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have edited my original question with output you asked.

Comment: @SouravBiswas Thanks for the info! Everything looks ok there. Try the GRUB changes and see if it boots faster.

Comment: `1min 58.551s plymouth-quit-wait.service` latest run (2nd reboot)

Comment: @SouravBiswas Try the `fsck` in my answer. If that doesn't help, you can try and uninstall `plymouth`. `sudo apt-get purge plymouth`.

Comment: It seems removing `plymouth` did the trick. Although I removed `psensor` as well. May be there is no connection but like to mention that. Please update your answer with plymouth removing step. I will mark it as accepted. I will also update my question with solution and latest figures. Please have a look

Comment: @SouravBiswas Glad that worked! I've updated my answer. Thanks!